# Generating new objects to the position of a random object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help, I have a code for generating a level, each time the generation happens randomly, so I can't make it so that when the trigger is reached on a certain section of the level, at the end of the level on the last platform, more platforms were generated, I tried to search for an object through `pos = GameObject.Find("Platform 4 End Platform(Clone)").transform.position;` , but in the end I did not come to success,can someone explain how to do it best? All the code is attached below, as I have a generation, etc.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using DG.Tweening;

public class LevelGeneratorRock : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject startPlatform, endPlatform, platformPrefab, triggerPlatform;

    private float blockWidth = 0.5f, blockHeight = 0.2f;

    [SerializeField]
    private int amountToSpawn = 100;
    private int beginAmount = 0;


    public Vector3 pos;



    private List<GameObject> spawnedPlatforms = new List<GameObject>();

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject playerPrefab;

    void Awake()
    {
        beginAmount = 0;
        amountToSpawn = 10;
        InstantiateLevel();
    }
    const int MAX_PLATFORMS = 100;
    void InstantiateLevel()
    {

        // Notice the conditional changed here
        for (int i = beginAmount; i < beginAmount + amountToSpawn; i++)
        {

            GameObject newPlatform;

            if (i == 0)
            {
                newPlatform = Instantiate(startPlatform);
            }
            else if (i == MAX_PLATFORMS)
            { // End Platform
                newPlatform = Instantiate(endPlatform);
                newPlatform.tag = "EndPlatform";
            }
            else if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                newPlatform = Instantiate(triggerPlatform);
                newPlatform.tag = "triggerPlatform";
            }
            else
            { // Normal platform
                newPlatform = Instantiate(platformPrefab);
            }




            spawnedPlatforms.Add(newPlatform);
            int left = Random.Range(0, 2);

            if (left == 0)
            {
               
                newPlatform.transform.position =
                    new Vector3(pos.x - blockWidth, pos.y + blockHeight, pos.z);

            }
            else
            {
               
                newPlatform.transform.position =
                    new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y + blockHeight, pos.z + blockWidth);

            }
            
            pos = newPlatform.transform.position;

            // fancy animation
            if (i < 25)
            {

                float pos = newPlatform.transform.position.y;

                newPlatform.transform.position =
                    new Vector3(newPlatform.transform.position.x,
                    newPlatform.transform.position.y - blockHeight * 3f,
                    newPlatform.transform.position.z);

                newPlatform.transform.DOLocalMoveY(pos, 0.3f).SetDelay(i * 0.1f);

            }

        } // for loop



    } // instantiate level

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("triggerPlatform"))
        {
            // Tell the level generator to spawn more platforms
            {
                beginAmount = beginAmount + 11;
                amountToSpawn = 10;
                InstantiateLevel();
            }
        }









    }
}// class
```

I will also attach a photo from the editor
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBAd0.png]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have all the platforms in the List spawnedPlatforms. You're already setting the tag too, so you could loop over the list and check the tag for "EndPlatform" right? If you're after a specific EndPlatform,

```
var platformToFind = "3";
foreach (var platform in spawnedPlatforms) {
    if (platform.tag == "EndPlatform" && platform.name.Contains(platformToFind)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Based on your comment, it sounds like you wish that every time the player jumps up 10 platforms, you want to create 10 more.

What this means is you need a trigger platform every 10 platforms. So you should change `if (i == amountToSpawn - 90)` to `if (i % 10 == 0)`. This is called the modulo operator, it gives you the remainder of a division. E.g. 13 % 10 = 3, or for our case: 10 % 0 = 0, 20 % 0 = 0, 30 % 0 = 0, etc.

It would look something like this:

```
void Awake()
{
    beginAmount = 0;
    amountToSpawn = 10;
    InstantiateLevel();
}
const int MAX_PLATFORMS = 100;
void InstantiateLevel()
{

// Notice the conditional changed here
for (int i = beginAmount; i < beginAmount + amountToSpawn; i++)  {

            GameObject newPlatform;

            if (i == 0) {
                newPlatform = Instantiate(startPlatform);
            } else if (i == MAX_PLATFORMS) { // End Platform
            } else if (i % 10 == 0) {
                newPlatform = Instantiate(triggerPlatform);
                newPlatform.tag = "triggerPlatform";
            } else { // Normal platform
            }
}
```

Then in your player script, you'd have something like:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
   if (other.gameObject.tag.CompareTag("triggerPlatform")) {
       // Tell the level generator to spawn more platforms
       levelGenerator.beginAmount = levelGenerator.beginAmount + 11;
       levelGenerator.amountToSpawn = 10;
       levelGenerator.InstantiateLevel();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a tag. Ie currently I have looks like this at the start of the scene I have platforms that go up randomly, the entire path of the platforms consists of a prefab, and that's 10 platforms before endPlatform I have is the trigger, and when it comes the character it needs to generate more platforms to the latest platform generation I can do, but it is not correct, ie I can't figure out how to track the location of endPlatform in the code to the new platform correctly generated for her.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I believe I better understand you now. Does that help?

Comment: I tried what you advised, my God it turns out I know so little) I got it but not much it's not what you need, swapn worked,but immediately before reaching the trigger, I will also attach all the details in the edited response

Comment: I think we are having difficulty understanding each other :( From your edit, it looks like you may have got the wrong idea from my code. So for example, your Player (the bird) should be checking for collision with the platform, how you have it now the platform is checking for collision against itself.

Perhaps take a break, think about it a bit and come back to it!

Comment: In any case, thank you for helping,I will try to understand!)